# What is the easiest way to prefer single entries in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a beginner with elastic search and I have a big Index with queries for each use case, but now I want to prefer ONE single entry to be shown at the first place but only in one special case.

For example in my index are

1. name: dog, home: couch
2. name: cat, home: couch
3. name: lion, home: jungle
4. name: big cat, home: jungle

I would like to have "cat" at the first place when I search for "couch", but not when I search for "jungle". For that case I get "big cat" at the first place at the moment.
That is the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: does this return required output? `{ "term" : { "home" : "couch" } }`

Comment: Hmm. In my case it would be { "term" : { "name" : "cat" } }, because I want the entry with the exact match with "cat", but my query seems to ignore it. I use a bool query in general. Could it be index or analyzer related?

Comment: if you search for cat and your `name` field is not analyzed then `{ "term" : { "name" : "cat" } }` would return only `name: dog, home: couch`. if the `name` field is analyzed you would get both records. you can check the mapping of the index to see if the field is analyzed.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it was analyzed. It was a bit of missing understanding from my side. I used the Analyzer anyway because i needed it at other queries. I solved it for my case with a boolean query where it "should" be cat und "must" be "couch". This changed the scoring to the direction of "cat" but only when I queried for "couch".

Answer (score 0):

My final approach is a boolean query where it "should" be cat und "must" be "couch". This changed the scoring to the direction of "cat" but only when I queried for "couch".